# JedisCluster : redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisNoReachableClusterNodeException: No reachable node in cluster

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I was trying to connect to JedisCluster  (ElastiCache Redis) from java. But I was getting JedisConnectionException with No reachable node in the cluster.

Here was my code to connect to JedisCluster

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        final GenericObjectPoolConfig poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(2000);
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(300);
        Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNode = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
        jedisClusterNode.add(new HostAndPort("mycachecluster.eaogs8.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com",6379));
        jedisClusterNode.add(new HostAndPort("mycachecluster.eaogs8.0002.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com",6379));
        JedisCluster jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNode,poolConfig);
        System.out.println("Cluster Size...." + jedisCluster.getClusterNodes().size());
        try{
            jedisCluster.set("foo", "bar");
            jedisCluster.get("foo");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            jedisCluster.close();
        }
    }
```

The exception I got after running this

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisNoReachableClusterNodeException: No reachable node in cluster
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnection(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:57)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:74)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:116)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.run(JedisClusterCommand.java:31)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.set(JedisCluster.java:103)
```

I have checked

```
telnet mycachecluster.eaogs8.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com 6379
```

as mentioned in [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.ConnectToCacheNode.html) I got the reply as Connected.

What is the issue here and why I am not able to connect to the JedisCluster using java?

Note :

I am using jedis version 2.9.0

Update:

In AWS **Encryption in-transit and Encryption at-rest are activated**

So

```
Jedis jedis = null;
        try{
            jedis = new Jedis(URI.create("rediss://mycachecluster.eaogs8.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379"));
            System.out.println(jedis.ping());
            System.out.println("XXXXX: "+jedis.get("c"));
        }
        catch(Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            jedis.close();
        }
```

works fine. But not the jedis cluster.

Comment: You might want to try out Redisson or Lettuce clients that have Redis Cluster with SSL support.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am using AWS Elasticache (cluster mode enabled) with no encryption in transit. In Jedis, I initialize only one HostPort i.e. the AWS Elasticache Redis configuration endpoint. 

How did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `URI.create("rediss://...")`, it's evident that you are using *Redis SSL Scheme* to create a successful connection by Jedis. But JedisCluster doesn't have SSL support yet.

There is a [pending feature request](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1210) and [pull request](https://github.com/redis/jedis/pull/1550) regarding this.

---

Update: JedisCluster has SSL/TLS support since Jedis version 3.1.0. Just choose any JedisCluster constructor with `boolean ssl` parameter and set the value to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The JedisCluster had some problems while connecting the redis cluster server with SSL enabled. Even with the latest revision(as of July 2020) we were getting the exception `JedisNoReachableClusterNodeException`. There are very less articles on the configurations required for various server requirements.

We needed the library in 2 languages, one in Java and the other in Python. For python I used the python redis-py-cluster. While for Java initially we tried with Jedis and then Jedis Cluster but both were not helpful.
So another library I found is

**Lettuce**

For a redis cluster server with SSL support the configuration is pretty straight forward and supports a builder pattern to construct the connection object with optional parameters. Here is the sample to create and connect to redis-cluster server

```
RedisURI redisURI = RedisURI.Builder.redis("<<Redis Server primary endpoint>>", 6379).withSsl(true).withVerifyPeer(false).build();
RedisClusterClient redisClient  = RedisClusterClient.create(redisURI);
StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, String> conn = redisClient.connect();
List<KeyValue<String, String>> res_1=  conn.sync().mget(keys...)_
conn.close();
```

But note that if the redis server is a single node instance then even Jedis library is also good to use.

Comment: Is this viable to handle massive requests?

Comment: I tested for around 5000 keys in mget with 4 requests in parallel and it worked well with this.